# Where is wine located on a fresh Ubuntu installation?

Tags: wine, software-installation

Well, I've installed Ubuntu & so far I love it. But is it just me or did Wine not come with the installation as cited [here](http://www.ubuntu.com/desktop)

I've used the previous version on the same machine with it included, up & running great. I understand it's in the software center & I can just download it from there. But, where is it on my newly installed OS? No searches of my system have found it?

Comment: There is no mention of "wine" on that page. " But, where is it on my newly installed OS" It is in the software center.

Answer (score 2):

Wine stores the stuff you do on in it in `.wine`, a hidden file in your home directory. Inside it is `drive_c`, which is a sort of virtual version of the Windows C drive, and where Wine installs the exe files.

You can check whether it is installed by running `wine --version` in terminal, and if it is not installed, you should be able to install Wine from [here](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/wine) [image: Install wine] .

If you cannot open exe's with it, you may need to edit `wine.desktop` in `/usr/share/applications`, and replace the `NoDisplay=true` line with `NoDisplay=false`.

Comment: I'm totally frustrated. there is no usr/share anywhere and how can i locate. why in ubuntu forum no one answer point to point. I better go back to mac os

Answer (score 1):

after you installed wine via the software center you can install windows installers by right clicking the installer and choose open with --> 'wine windows program loader'. however you first need to allow the file to executing. to do this you right click, select properties and go to the permissions tab. here check the 'Allow executing file as program' box. you can configer some settings of wine with the program 'Configure Wine'.

you can also take a look at the program 'Play on Linux' it helps you to manage installed programs. it creates a new instance of wine which allow you to have specific configurations per program and it has pre configured installs for a lot of programs (mostly games)

I am not sure what programs you want to run under wine but in general I would advise first to search for native alternatives on Linux since not all programs will run good under wine.